# How to fill Access textbox with "Add Contact From Outlook" macro

Tags: ms-access, outlook

The Access template called "Assets" has a great feature in which you can click a button that runs a macro called "AddContactFromOutlook". This opens your Outlook contacts and lets you choose a name to add to a Contacts table.

The problem is, I can't find any basic instructions on how to use it. The macro commands are very simple: basically just "AddContactFromOutlook".

I copied a table from the Assets template into my database, created a form and added a button to run the macro, and it works fine. But when I did the same with a table and form of my own creation, I got this error:

`The Command or Action 'AddFromOutlook' isn't available now`

I suspect the problem is the names of my fields, although this error sounds like something different.

I've searched online, and mostly see information about *special* cases, not the basics.

Comment: I tested this. I built Contacts table with table template. Built form based on that table. Created a button with embedded macro. It all works. Button click opens Outlook contacts window where I can select a contact and it imports into table. If your table does not have expected field names, expect failure.

Comment: An alternative is to set a link to Contacts folder with External Data.

Comment: @June7 I can't find "table templates" in Access 2016. Where are they? More importantly, is there a list somewhere of "expected field names"?

Comment: I use Access 2010. Found Contacts table template under Create > Templates > Quick Start. I don't know of a list of field names the AddFromOutlook method expects. They most likely coincide with attribute names used by Outlook Contacts.